# Vertically position DIV in the center of parent DIV?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to position my `caption-wrap` div vertically centeredwithin the `metaslider` div. Can someone help?

http://jsfiddle.net/LuLkza9L/

```
<div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;" class="metaslider metaslider-flex metaslider-364 ml-slider">

    <div id="metaslider_container_364">
        <div id="metaslider_364" class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li style="display: block; width: 100%;" class="slide-370 ms-image">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/700x300" height="300" width="700" alt="" class="slider-364 slide-370" />
                    <div class="caption-wrap">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h2 style="text-align:center">Can I place this in centre?</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Comment: Oh horrors, those inline style's and image size attributes...

Comment: Tidied it a little :-) http://jsfiddle.net/LuLkza9L/3/

Comment: Resolved: http://jsfiddle.net/LuLkza9L/6/ Will post a thorough reply soon :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved:
http://jsfiddle.net/LuLkza9L/6/

```
.caption-wrap {
   position: absolute; 
   top: 45%; 
   left: 0;
   text-align: center; 
   width: 100%; 
}

.caption-wrap span { 
    color: red;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: italic;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
    pointer-events: none;

}

.metaslider {
  position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really simple. Just add `list-style:none;`

here is the JSFiddle with all your classes in tact.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/LuLkza9L/4/)

```css
* {
    border:black 1px solid;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" />
         <h2>Can I place this in centre?</h2>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Unfortunately, I was hoping to float the text over the image too.